# How to differentiate mat-select style and mat-paginator mat-select styles?

Tags: css, sass, angular-material, angular7

I'm creating angular 7 web app , and using one mat-select dropdown and one mat-paginator. now i'm hide mat-select down arrow.

[Here is the mat-select docs.](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples)

[image]

```
//hide down arrow
::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 0px solid transparent; 
border-right: 0px solid transparent;
border-top: 5px solid;
margin: 0 4px;
}
```

after that problem comes in mat-paginator, paginator dropdown arrow not coming.
how to differentiate both dropdown.

[image: here is the mat-paginator and item per pages 10 dropdown arrow not coming.]

i want to dropdown arrow in mat-paginator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the following `css` definition.

```
:host ::ng-deep.mat-paginator .mat-select-arrow {
  border-left: 5px solid transparent !important;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks sir, i request to you please give me some tips for UI design or any tutorials.

Comment: Although my answer concerns `CSS`, I don't consider myself a `CSS` expert. There are many good sites on the internet that explain the topic in detail. Since Angular Material mainly uses `CSS flexbox layout`, I find most solutions to related problems on amazing guide at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.